# Relatively Open Complex Sets

Tags: complex-analysis

I have come to the following exercise:

> If $X \subset S$, show that the relatively open subsets of $X$ are
> precisely those sets that can be expressed as the intersection of $X$
> with an open subset of $S$.

Something I also want to understande is about the concepts of relatively open and open difference, as in understanding why of $[0,1) = (-1, 1) \cap [0,1]$.

Comment: What does it mean for you that a set is relatively open?

Comment: It means to me as in $[0, 1)$ or in $(0,1] $ but not $(0,1)$ for example.

Comment: I don't want examples I want the definition.

Comment: I don't have any idea of what the definition is.

Comment: Ok, go look it up in your notes/book.

Comment: This is usually called the "[subspace topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subspace_topology)."

Comment: This _is_ the definition.